# Changes within element doesn't show/apply

Tags: javascript, dom

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aa1z1m8t/3/

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) that allows the creation of treeviews as a bootstrap component, however I think this is more of a JS question than a library-use question.

I want to change title of the `li` element (tree node) upon selection, but the applied changes simply do not show! As if the element doesn't refreshes.

I've tried using the library's event, I've tried using the jQuery's click event (both, `click` and `on` variants), but to no avail. I've also tried various reflow tricks.

How can I force a refresh?

Note that the treeview is being generated and appended to DOM via JS.

To sum up: I wanted to change the node's title on selection, but changes aren't applied for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to understand your problem, but i am not completely sure.

https://jsfiddle.net/aa1z1m8t/11/

```
function CreateTreeView() {
  $('#tree').treeview({
    'data': treedata,
    'onNodeSelected': function(event, data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

I build a function to create the treeview and call it every time a event is fireing.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. Event firing isn't the problem. Try changing the text "fun is now" within event handler. My problem was that when I changed the text to "hello", it simply didn't show. As if I never changed the text.

Comment: it seems to be an issue with the treeview plugin. the plugin itself seems to be a bit older/ not maintained anymore. Choose another one.